# Custom Layout for PopupMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I am new to Android, trying to crate a custom layout for `android.widget.PopupMenu`
I searched but could not find a working solution.

I want

[image]

**I want left side green line, bottom menu items separating line.
That is a customised layout for PopupMenu items**

I need to use android.widget.PopupMenu only.
I tried this, but not working.

In `//app/src/main/res/layout/menu_item_more.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFAAAA">
</LinearLayout>
```

In `//app/src/main/res/menu/more_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_notification_news"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_more"
        android:title="알림/소식" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_employment_info"
        android:title="취업정보" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_public_relation"
        android:title="시정홍보" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_preferences"
        android:title="환경설정" />
</menu>
```

In Activity

```
var moreMenu: View = findViewById(R.id.more_menu)
popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, moreMenu)
popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.more_menu, popupMenu.menu)
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
popupMenu.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating your own component extending from PopupMenu and overriding the following method? This method is the one responsible for returning the list layout.

```
public ListView getMenuListView() {
        if (!mPopup.isShowing()) {
            return null;
        }
        return mPopup.getPopup().getListView();
    }
```

Hope i helped! Let me know if that worked! :)